# Bubble tree in d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, raphael

Is there an equivalent implementation of a [Bubble Tree](http://vis4.net/blog/posts/tutorial-bubble-tree/) in D3? In the link I provided, the Bubble Tree was implemented in RaphaelJS and jQuery.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you already searched the web, I think the odds of your question being answered here in the way you want are pretty slim.  I think that a bubble chart is perfectly within the realm of possibilities with D3... Why don't you try and start making one and then ask questions surrounding the challenges that you come across in doing so?

Comment: @mbeasley: I have already started. But I'm letting this question stay. In almost all my previous questions, I was surprised when someone pointed me to an existing implementation hidden inside a small wiki somewhere :)

Comment: Fair enough.  Be sure to post a link here to the implementation if you feel like sharing it.  That would be great to see in D3!  Good luck

Comment: @mbeasley: Yes definitely. Thanks!

Comment: Please check [InfoVis](http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html). They have similar graph like what you are looking may be it will give you some idea. But unlike Raphael it uses Canvas instead of SVG.

Comment: You can use these examples : 1. [Circle packing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530) 2. [Zoomable packing](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html) (modified circle packing) 3. [Force-collapsible bubbles](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) All these use data to be in tree format and visualize them in bubbles. They are easy to use, but you can make some changes if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The straight answer to your question is no.

Using the resources at https://github.com/okfn/bubbletree/tree/master/build, the information you already know, and the information provided on http://d3js.org/ and through D3's documentation on GitHub, you should be able to conjure up your own bubble tree for D3!

This is a piece of JavaScript I used a long time ago to visualize binary tree data:

```
var updateVisual;

updateVisual = function() {
    var drawTree, out;
    drawTree = function(out, node) {
        var col, gray, i, line, lineElt, lines, sub, _results, _results1;
        if (node.lines) {
            out.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "<b>leaf</b>: " + node.lines.length + " lines, " + Math.round(node.height) + " px";
            lines = out.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            lines.style.lineHeight = "6px";
            lines.style.marginLeft = "10px";
            i = 0;
            _results = [];
            while (i < node.lines.length) {
                line = node.lines[i];
                lineElt = lines.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
                lineElt.className = "lineblock";
                gray = Math.min(line.text.length * 3, 230);
                col = gray.toString(16);
                if (col.length === 1) col = "0" + col;
                lineElt.style.background = "#" + col + col + col;
                console.log(line.height, line);
                lineElt.style.width = Math.max(Math.round(line.height / 3), 1) + "px";
                _results.push(i++);
            }
            return _results;
        } else {
            out.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "<b>node</b>: " + node.size + " lines, " + Math.round(node.height) + " px";
            sub = out.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            sub.style.paddingLeft = "20px";
            i = 0;
            _results1 = [];
            while (i < node.children.length) {
                drawTree(sub, node.children[i]);
                _results1.push(++i);
            }
            return _results1;
        }
    };
    out = document.getElementById("btree-view");
    out.innerHTML = "";
    return drawTree(out, editor.getDoc());
};
```

Just insert some circular elements and manipulate it a bit to style in a circular manor and you should have a good program set!

Comment: You misunderstand. A bubble *tree* is a way of visualising hierarchical data; it has nothing to do with bubble sort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I didn't add the text or decorations, but it's the meat and potatoes:

```js
function bubbleChart(config) {
 var aspectRatio = 1,
      margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
      radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt(),
      scan = function(f, data, a) {
        a = a === undefined ? 0 : a;
        var results = [a];
        data.forEach(function(d, i) {
          a = f(a, d);
          results.push(a);
        });
        return results;
      },
      colorScale = d3.scale.category20(),
      result = function(selection) {
  selection.each(function(data) {
   var outerWidth = $(this).width(),
          outerHeight = outerWidth / aspectRatio,
          width = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          smallestDimension = Math.min(width, height),
          sum = data[1].reduce(function(a, d) {
            return a + d[1];
          }, 0),
          radiusFractions = data[1].map(function(d) {
            return Math.sqrt(d[1] / sum);
          }),
          radiusNormalSum = radiusFractions.reduce(function(a, d) {
            return a + d;
          }, 0),
          scanned = scan(function(a, d) {
            return a + d;
          }, radiusFractions.map(function(d) {
            return d / radiusNormalSum;
          }), 0);
   radiusScale.domain([0, sum]).range([0, smallestDimension / 6]);
      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll('svg').data([data]),
          svgEnter = svg.enter().append('svg');
   svg.attr('width', outerWidth).attr('height', outerHeight);
   var gEnter = svgEnter.append('g'),
          g = svg.select('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ' ' + margin.top + ')'),
          circleRing = g.selectAll('circle.ring').data(data[1]),
          circleRingEnter = circleRing.enter().append('circle').attr('class', 'ring');
      circleRing.attr('cx', function(d, i) {
        return smallestDimension / 3 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (scanned[i] + scanned[i + 1]) / 2) + width / 2;
      }).attr('cy', function(d, i) {
        return smallestDimension / 3 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (scanned[i] + scanned[i + 1]) / 2) + height / 2;
      }).attr('r', function(d) {
        return radiusScale(d[1]);
      }).style('fill', function(d) {
        return colorScale(d[0]);
      });
      var circleMain = g.selectAll('circle#main').data([data[0]]),
          circleMainEnter = circleMain.enter().append('circle').attr('id', 'main');
      circleMain.attr('cx', width / 2).attr('cy', height / 2).attr('r', radiusScale(sum)).style('fill', function(d) {
        return colorScale(d);
      });
  });
 };
 result.aspectRatio = function(value) {
  if(value === undefined) return aspectRatio;
  aspectRatio = value;
  return result;
 };
 result.margin = function(value) {
  if(value === undefined) return margin;
  margin = value;
  return result;
 };
 return result;
}

var myBubbleChart = bubbleChart().margin({
  top: 1,
  right: 1,
  bottom : 1,
  left: 1
});
var data = ['Random Names, Random Amounts', [['Immanuel', .4], ['Pascal', 42.9], ['Marisa', 3.3], ['Hadumod', 4.5], ['Folker', 3.2], ['Theo', 4.7], ['Barnabas', 1.0], ['Lysann', 11.1], ['Julia', .7], ['Burgis', 28.2]]];
d3.select('#here').datum(data).call(myBubbleChart);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="here"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the pack layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) , basically you can bind any data you want to the shapes in the graph and custom parameters for them to position well respect to each other. Another alternative would be the force layout.